# login form does not appear

Tags: php, codeigniter, tankauth

I am new to CodeIgniter and I use Tank Auth for my login form. When I try to put Tank Auth in my template, the login form doesn’t appear at all. I didn’t change anything but the controller.

Here is my controller code:

```php
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
    $this->load->library('tank_auth');
    //$this->load->model('users_model');
}
public function index(){
    if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {
        $data['loginform']='login_form';
        $this->load->view('tampilan',$data);
        //redirect('/auth/login/');
    } else {
        $data['user_id']    = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
        $data['username']   = $this->tank_auth->get_username();
        $this->load->view('welcome', $data);
    }               
}
```

and here is my template in the view folder:

```
<div id="page">

<div id="bg1">

    <div id="bg2">

        <div id="bg3">

            <!-- content -->

            <?php  $this->load->view($loginform); ?>

            <!-- end content -->

            <!-- sidebar -->

            <?php echo $this->load->view('content'); ?>

            <!-- end sidebar -->

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

It’s simple code, I think, because I just change the controller, but why doesn’t it appear in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

The code, in itself, looks correct. What I can say is that might be that you're calling the wrong view, and have an error reporting level too low to show you errors. I mean:

1. Is your login_form.php view a custom one? Is the path right? Try using a simple almost empty view (don't know, with just an "hello world" text in it?) to see if it gets called correctly.
2. If you're using the default login_form.php view provided by Tank Auth, and you copied the content as is, the view should be inside the folder `auth` (so it comes in the downloaded package). Therefore you should call it with `$data['auth/login_form'];` in your controller,
3. In the eventuality of point 2), the original Tank Auth login_form.php contains *a lot* of variables which happen to be undefined in your code. If you don't display errors, you get a blank page then. Set the ENVIRONMENT to "development" in index.php, and if that's not enough place this at the beginning of your index.php

   ```
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors',1);
   ```

   To just test the functinality of Tank Auth, try calling it with the original controller by going to `http://www.yoursite.com/index.php/auth` . If that works, have a look at the `login()` method of the auth controller, you'll see how and which variable the original `login_form.php` needs.
4. Minor point, you don't need to `echo` a view, so `$this->load->view('content');` is enought.

Comment: First I would like say thank you for your help to answer of my problem mate. For point 1 I am not customize at all for login_form.php, yup the path it's correctly right, yes it can gets call correctly if I try hello world text. In point 2, yes I use the default login_form view provide by Tank Auth, I tried `$data['auth/login_form'];` than I have an errors. At point 3 sorry I don't know what your mean to set the ENVIRONMENT in index.php?could you tell more specifically?

Comment: Update condition, I was checked login_form view in auth folder, I forgot that I was put php comment `//` in `$show_captcha`. Thats why the login_form cannot shown in my template, but when I remove the comments `//` it appear some error like this:
`A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: login_by_username

Filename: auth/login_form.php

Line Number: 9
`
could you tell me why?

thanks

Comment: Look at the login() method in auth controller: as I said, you'll see where the view variables for the login_form.php are created. Anyway, that is a config option